# Seaborn scatterplot addition legend items

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot

I'm seeing '1 and 2' as additional labels in my legend for a seaborn scatterplot. They'll disappear when I set the legend to False, but so does the legend I do want in there. 
Any idea where this comes from and how to prevent it from appearing?

This sample code generates the image with the issue;

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'restHR': np.random.randint(40,65, size=(100,)),
                   'Time': np.random.randint(0,10, size=(100,))})

sns.set()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = sns.scatterplot(df['Time'], df['restHR'], size=2, alpha=0.3, label="Race",linewidths=0)

plt.legend(frameon=False, bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5), loc="center left",prop={'size': 8})
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of `size=2`? Usually you would do `size="columnname"` to group sizes. Using an integer instead is allowed by the documentation, however it does not explain what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from `size=2`. The `size` parameter is used when you want varied size for the points given a grouped variable.

I am not sure why you have it there, but if you want to adjust the size of the symbol, use `s=2` instead.

Comment: excellent, thanks! This was a consequence of me plotting the size based on another variable previously, but now wanting to set it to a fixed size. 's=' does indeed do the trick. 

Still makes me wonder where exactly the two additional values come from and why it is 2 values? (as opposed to 1 for the additional variable?). Using size=4  gives me 2 values: 3 and 4 for instance.

Comment: I am not sure. It seems to me that `seaborn` is trying to extrapolate/interpolate integer values when used as input for the 'size' parameter. I tried a few things, if you create a column and assign 2 to all values of that column, it would give you the same result. However, when assigning 1 and 4 to the values, `seaborn` also creates legend symbols for 2 and 3, although no values are present in that column. Working with strings (e.g. 'foo' and 'bar' instead of 1 and 4) didn't give me this problem.